# How to handle long integers in TCL with binary format command?

Tags: tcl

```
% binary scan [ binary format i* 146366987889541120] B* g
integer value too large to represent
```

Can anyone help me in computing a long integer value using binary format commnand .
 But we are getting error and there is no way of representing 'l' in the syntax (like in the format command `format %lx  146366987889541120`).

```
% format %lx  146366987889541120
208000000000000
%
%
% format %x  146366987889541120
0
%
```

Can anyone sugggest me a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Just use

```
format %llb 146366987889541120
```

If you want a binary string representing this number.

---

If you don't deal with wide integer (bigger than 64-bit, added with Tcl 8.5), you can use

```
binary scan [ binary format w 146366987889541120] B* g
```

But if you have longer integers, the best workarround that I found is:

```
# convert a binary string to a large integer
binary scan $bytes H* temp
set num [format %lli 0x$temp]
# convert a number to a binary string.
set bytes [binary format H* [format %llx $num]]
```

This has some bugs (leading zero), so you want to add a 0 for `binary format`.

```
set hex [format %llx $num]
if {[string length $hex]%2} {set hex 0$hex}
set bytes [binary format H* $hex]
```

But I doubt that this approach yields the best performance.